# Some statements for matrix and its determinant, please help me find the correct answer.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Which of the following statements is always TRUE

A. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with all entries being positive, then $\det(A)>0$.

B. If $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices with $\det(A)>0$ and $\det(B)>0$, then also $\det(A+B)>0$.

C. If $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB=0$, then both $A$ and $B$ are singular.

D. If rows of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ are linearly independent, then $\det(A^{T}A)>0$.

E. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with $A^2=I_n$, then $\det(A)=1$.

My analysis:

A - this is obvious false. Easy to find a $2\times 2$ matrix example.

B - I am not sure.

C - this is false as $B$ could be zero matrix.

D - Use row reduction, we can get $\det(A)=0$. And $\det(A^{T}A)=\det(A^{T})\det(A)=(\det(A))^2=0$. So it is false.

E - $\det(A^2)=(\det(A))^2=(\det(I_n))^2=1$, so $\det(A)=1$ or $\det(A)=-1$. It is false.

Please check if my analysis is correct.

Source of this question - it is the problem 5 of [Purdue MA26500 (Linear Algebra) Fall 2022 Midterm 1](https://www.math.purdue.edu/php-scripts/courses/oldexams/serve_file.php?file=26500E1-F2022.pdf).

Comment: My answer is B. I find the cases that can prove the others are wrong. But I could not prove C is TRUE directly. Any hint?

Comment: You should include your comment in the question itself. Otherwise, the question may be closed for missing context.

Comment: The statement B is actually not true. Nor is C.

Comment: A, B, C, E, are all false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

B) $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$

C) A non singular, B zero matrix.

D) True. $\det(A^T A) = \det(A^T) \det A = (\det A)^2 > 0$, because $\det A$ is nonzero.

E)  $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Got it, thanks. I misread the statement D. It is actually linear independent, not linear dependent.